# Unity 2017 and HTC Vive

Tags: unity-game-engine, htc-vive

According to [the documentation of Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OpenVRControllers.html), I should use `Axis1D.SecondaryIndexTrigger` to be able to detect if the user pushes the joystick's trigger identified by the number 7 (on the image of the HTC Vive and in the table describing the inputs, both are displayed in the above link).

However, when I type `if(Input.GetAxis(Axis1D.SecondaryIndexTrigger))`, the compiler says :

> error CS0103: The name `Axis1D' does not exist in the current context

`Axis1D` seems to be necessarily imported or somewhat to be usable.
How could I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

For Htc Vive you need to import following **SteamVR Plugin** from the unity [assetstore](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/steamvr-plugin-32647)

For step by step visit  getting started guide [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/149239/htc-vive-tutorial-unity) for setting up Htc vive

Comment: Oculus or HTC Vive Integration (I use the latter)?

Comment: For htc vive controllers or Oculus controllers you can use SteamVr plugin , I have updated the answer .. For the input Scripts , visit the updated getting  started link , information there is pretty clear . To my knowledge  "Axis1D.SecondaryIndexTrigger" you used is for oculus touch controllers.

Comment: `Axis1D...` is normally supposed to be used for both headsets, to abstract them - according to the doc I linked.